# How to replace the Marina logo with my own?

Tags: css

Im very very new to CSS and making my own website, I used this template - https://smftricks.com/index.php?action=store;sa=view&id=41 and this is my website
https://westcoastresponders.com/index.php Im trying to replace the Marina image with my own but im not sure where to find it. or how to replace it. Aswell as adding my own Favicon.

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well looking to the template it says that the logo is here

> ../images/custom/logo.png

Logo is defined as a background of div class logo

```
.logo a {
    background: url(../images/custom/logo.png);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 237px;
    height: 111px;
}
```

Comment: I am glad that you made it. Please mark the answer as accepted in order to help others in the community with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

replace the Marina logo image with your own website logo and path to replace the logo is Themes/MarinaTheme/images/custom/logo.png